# R: creating a symmetric matrix with xtabs

Tags: r, matrix

I have three models: M1, M2 and M3. I compare the models pair-wise and get a score. I do only the one-way comparisons. M1 and M2 but not M2 and M1 as it will be he same. I want to convert these to a symmetrix matrix.

I was able to convert the data set into matrix using xtabs but it doesn't have the M1-M1 and M3-M3 distance.

```
d <- data.frame(M1 = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M2", "M2", "M3"),
            M2 = c("M2", "M3", "M4", "M3", "M4", "M4"),
            C = c(1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 6))

dm = xtabs(C~M1+M2, data=d)


> d
  M1 M2 C
1 M1 M2 1
2 M1 M3 1
3 M1 M4 4
4 M2 M3 2
5 M2 M4 2
6 M3 M4 6
> dm
    M2
M1   M2 M3 M4
  M1  1  1  4
  M2  0  2  2
  M3  0  0  6
```

I tried copying the upper triangle to the lower triangle but it doesn't work properly as it is not a symmetric matrix. I would like to know how to include M1-M1 and M3-M3 distance and make it a symmetric matrix. Even though the distance is 0 will it be a problem when I try to convert the matrix into a dist() object?

```
> dm[lower.tri(dm)] <- t(dm)[lower.tri(dm)]
> dm
    M2
M1   M2 M3 M4
  M1  1  1  4
  M2  1  2  2
  M3  4  2  6
```

Comment: Your posted data does not correspond to your images, there is no `"M4"`. And don't post images, please.

Comment: @Rui thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: one way; set the same levels: `d[1:2] <- lapply(d[1:2], factor, levels=unique(unlist(d[1:2])))` , then just `dm + t(dm)`

Comment: @user20650 Thank you for the answer. This one works. However I do not fully understand what the first line is doing. Can you please explain?

Comment: @SriniShine ; The first line is a way to get the same levels (M1 to M4) on
each dimension of the table - which I assumed (rightly or wrongly) was required. One way to do this is to set the variables to factors with the same set of factor levels. The previous code gives a quick way to write
`lvl <- unique(unlist(d[c("M1", "M2")])) ; 
d$M1 <- factor(d$M1, levels=lvl) ; 
d$M2 <- factor(d$M2, levels=lvl)`

Comment: @user20650 thank you. If you can post this as an answer I could accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a symmetric matrix, you likely want set the same levels (M1 to M4) on each dimension:

One way to do this is to set the variables to factors with the same set of factor levels.

```
d[c("M1", "M2")] <- lapply(d[c("M1", "M2")], factor, levels=unique(unlist(d[c("M1", "M2")])))
```

You can then use `xtabs` as before, and add the result to the transpose of the result.

```
dm <- xtabs(C ~ M1 + M2, data=d)

dm + t(dm)

#    M2
#M1   M1 M2 M3 M4
#  M1  0  1  1  4
#  M2  1  0  2  2
#  M3  1  2  0  6
#  M4  4  2  6  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Add its transpose.  That gives the diagonal twice so subtract it out.

```
dm + t(dm) - diag(diag(dm))
```

giving:

```
    M2
M1   M2 M3 M4
  M1  1  1  4
  M2  1  2  2
  M3  4  2  6
```

If we know that all elements are non-negative then this would also work:

```
pmax(dm, t(dm))
```